How to override query parameter of original websocket request after extenal authentication?
I use nginx external authentication and have a problem when a request is a websocket request. As a webscoket request hasn't headers it passes jwt token in query string parameter access_token.
Nginx goes to an external authenticator that returns Authorization header in a response with a new token (Bearer ...). I need to replace access_token of the original request with the token from Authotization header.
I've tried to at least append it with a new query parameter but it doesn't work (let alone I need to cut off the Bearer  prefix):
auth_request_set $bearer $upstream_http_authorization;
set $args $args&token=$bearer;

Could anyone help me?
I've configured ngnix:
auth_request_set $bearer $upstream_http_authorization;
set $args $args&token=$bearer;

I expect it append to query string a new parameter token with a value from Authorization header of a authorization subrequest.
